# Can I build my own secure communication protocol with ECDH, public-keys, AES using .NET?

Tags: .net, cryptography

I was recently trying to figure out a way of securing communications between a server and a client in a single-server multi-client system. Not having done much in the area of cryptography, I was hoping that people would have valuable input or feedback in case I missed something cruical.

If it matters, the .NET Framework 4.0 is going to be used.
Now on to the fun part:

1. The client establishes an unsecured connection to the server (most likely a RESTful call), asking for the server's public key (in case it is unknown) and a (pseudo-random) initialization vector. At this point, the client will also submit his public key if it was unknown before.
2. Both parties use Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (hash-based or hmac-based key derivation function, I'm not 100% sure yet; ideas?) to generate a secret key (using [System.Security.Cryptography.ECDiffieHellmanCng](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng.aspx))
3. Both parties calculate a derived initialization vector - e.g. by applying a [keyed hash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.keyedhashalgorithm.aspx) using the client's salted password hash as a key.
4. The client resumes communication using symmetric encryption (AES or Rijndael?) with the secret key generated during (2) and the modified initialization vector of (3), hopefully making the session secure.

Now I do wonder:

- is this approach too complicated?
- are there weak points that need improving? if so, do you have a proposal to fix it?

Comment: For #4, in .NET AES and Rijndael are the same thing. THe AesManaged and RijdaelManaged classes are the same. `AesManaged` is just a wrapper around `RijndaelManaged`.

Comment: I would really suggest using SSL instead of reinventing it.

Comment: @vcsjones: In every framework that is true - Rijndael IS the AES (Advanced Encryption Standard).

Comment: @vcsjones and @Noon Silk: Not necessarily true, and not true of .NET. AES is the Rijndael algorithm restricted to the 128 bit block size and the 128, 192, and 256 bit key sizes. Rijndael itself, and .NET's Rijndael implementation, supports other block sizes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And you protect against Man-in-the-Middle how?

Basically, how do you verify the server giving you the public key, is the actual server. This is what root certificates in TLS and chain-of-authority are for. Have you considered just using TLS and purchasing a SSL cert for the server? This would solve the MitM problem and perhaps a larger one: you wouldn't need to be writing your own crypto wrapper, where any subtle mistake (or even vulnerable practice) you introduce becomes a liability.

If you use WCF, then out of the box, it won't trust self-signed certificates.

See, [Best Practices for Security in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731059.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Excellent point; one that I have not considered before as I assumed it as granted. As for TLS, I am considering it, but I am not 100% certain if I am willing to invest into issued certificates for my private and humble project just yet.

Comment: @Manny: The cost of issued certificates has been driven to zero - eg [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/?app=1).

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is pretty close to how TLS/SSL works. Why not just use that?

Comment: TSL/SSL is certainly one way I am considering. Pesky penny-pincher that I am, I was considering alternative approaches that require little less investment.

Comment: @Manny Why does SSL require investment? You can always create your own CA and sign certs yourself.